# Do I have to play Online to unlock Custom Games

Tags: call-of-duty-infinite-warfare

I was watching an Infinite Warfare video and the saw on the person's screen that they were in the Multiplayer section. There was Public Match, Custom Game, and Store, and Custom Game was locked.

Will I have to play Online before I can access the Custom Game section?

Comment: Try picking a rig first.  This COD is different than others in that it sort of has an opening cut scene that is played _I believe_ when you first select Online Play.  After that cut scene and you chose your rig, see if its unlocked.